# PHP - urlencode spaces to "-" character

Tags: php

My laravel application is enconding my url spaces to the + sign. Is it possible to convert to the - sign?

Example present url:

http://merkat.local/blog/detalhe/Web+Dev+Post

Goal:
http://merkat.local/blog/detalhe/Web-Dev-Post

Answer (score 0):

Answer is **NO**, because it is URL.

from dev.mozzila

> For application/x-www-form-urlencoded, spaces are to be replaced by +,
> so one may wish to follow a encodeURIComponent() replacement with an
> additional replacement of %20 with +.

[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve this by creating a helper function with this code:

```
function create_slug($string){
    $slug=preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9-]+/', '-', $string);
    return $slug;
}
```

Comment: but - is not space. It is not same as + char. You need use replace.